# Mysql count(*) based in two relations

Tags: mysql

I would like to count(*) how much customers have created a post or made a comment. If the same customer has made several posts and comments, it should count only once.

---

Customer Table:
<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd> <kbd>**`Name`**</kbd>  <kbd>**`...`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`Jonh`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2`</kbd>  <kbd>`Mark`</kbd>  
<kbd>`3`</kbd>  <kbd>`King`</kbd>  
<kbd>`4`</kbd>  <kbd>`Doe`</kbd>

Post Table:
<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd> <kbd>**`USER_ID`**</kbd><kbd>**`...`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      
<kbd>`2`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      
<kbd>`3`</kbd>  <kbd>`3`</kbd>      
<kbd>`4`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>

Comment Table:
<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd> <kbd>**`USER_ID`**</kbd><kbd>**`...`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      
<kbd>`2`</kbd>  <kbd>`3`</kbd>      
<kbd>`3`</kbd>  <kbd>`3`</kbd>      
<kbd>`4`</kbd>  <kbd>`4`</kbd>

It should return count(*) = 3
(**user_id**: 1, 3 and 4).

Comment: What should be the desired output for the data that you have posted ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 It should return count(*) = 3 (user_id: 1, 3 and 4).

Comment: what about `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) AS posts` ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 This is to count how many customers have interacted with my platform, posting or even commenting.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT p.USER_ID) AS posts, COUNT (DISTINCT c.USER_ID) AS comments FROM Post p INNER JOIN Comment c ON (p.USER_ID = c.USER_ID)` This should count only these USER_IDs, who made both posts AND comments. Not tested, just as an idea

Comment: @ddlab I tried it but didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. It worked for me and returns what you're looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT( USER_ID ) AS TOTAL
FROM (
SELECT USER_ID
FROM POSTS
UNION
SELECT USER_ID
FROM COMMENTS
)X
```

I used POSTS and COMMENTS as table names bc I was unsure what your exact table names are, so make sure to change these in your query.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Just to learn, whats the function of the X in the end?

Comment: X is just an alias for the temporary table created by the subquery.  Using an alias allows you to refer to it in the outer select statement as well even though it is not in my example.

Comment: Can you also help me to get the top 10 ordered user IDs that have more comments + posts interactions?

Comment: Try this query. You may want to limit the fields selected for output or you may want all of them.  You can decide.

Comment: `SELECT * , USERPOSTS + USERCOMMENTS AS TOTALACTIVITY
FROM (

SELECT CUSTOMERS. * , (

SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM POSTS
WHERE POSTS.USER_ID = CUSTOMERS.ID
) AS USERPOSTS, (

SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM COMMENTS
WHERE COMMENTS.USER_ID = CUSTOMERS.ID
) AS USERCOMMENTS
FROM CUSTOMERS
)x
ORDER BY TOTALACTIVITY DESC 
LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) FROM (
SELECT USER_ID FROM POST_TABLE 
UNION
SELECT USER_ID FROM COMMENT_TABLE
)
```

Comment: Almost, you forgot to add `...) as c`

Comment: @Xorifelse I don't think that's necessary!

Comment: @Martin SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias